# Block the ui after expanding a collapsible div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I am making ajax call to get some data. I am showing a spinner and blocking  the ui by the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  $(".spinner").show();
  $('#shadow').addClass('blocker');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".spinner").hide();
    $('#shadow').removeClass('blocker');
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 45%;
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.shadow {
  z-index: 900
}
.blocker {
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>1Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Twitter Bootstrap?</a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>3Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="shadow"></div>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>
```

This code working fine till I expend a link. If I hit button after expending any link then the black layer not taking full height of the page.

Steps to reproduce:-

- expend any link
- hit button
- scroll down to see the issue.

I tried to user overflow property but no luck.

**How can the black layer take full height in all cases (with link expend)?**

Comment: try this .blocker{position: fixed;}

Comment: turn your block position absolute to fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `.blocker{position: fixed;}`

```js
function myFunction() {
  $(".spinner").show();
  $('#shadow').addClass('blocker');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".spinner").hide();
    $('#shadow').removeClass('blocker');
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 45%;
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.shadow {
  z-index: 900
}
.blocker {
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;/* change absolute to fixed */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>1Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Twitter Bootstrap?</a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
            </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>3Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
        <p>2Div</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="shadow"></div>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>
```